# Add Google Analytics to Nextjs app with next-redux-wrapper

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, next.js

I have created a nextjs app with redux wrapper

```
class MyApp extends React.Component<AppProps> {
   
    public static getInitialProps = wrapper.getInitialAppProps(store => async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
```

I am now trying integrate google analytics to the app ( G4 ). Though many documentations explains how to add with useEffect, guides are little disconnected on how to use them while app extends component and not using hooks.

Do i need to use componentMount methods or a better approach exists like upgrading this implementation to functional component?

Answer (score 0):

Converted the app as a functional component and used useEffect

```
  const MyApp = (AppProps) => {
      const router = useRouter();
      useEffect(() => {
```

and then

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = wrapper.getInitialAppProps(store => async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
```